# Ошибка "expected #EOF" в PHP скрипте

Tags: php

Вот скрипт, пишет ошибку expected #EOF

```
error_reporting (-1);

$anonDice1 = mt_rand(1,6);
$compDice1 = mt_rand(1,6);
$anonDice2 = mt_rand(1,6);
$compDice2 = mt_rand(1,6);

echo "У анона выпало {$anonDice1} и {$anonDice2}\nУ компьютера выпало {$compDice1} и {$compDice2}\n";

$anonSum - ($anonDice1 + $anonDice2);
$compSum - ($compDice1 + $compDice2);

if (($anonDice1 == $anonDice2) && ($compDice1 == $compDice2)); {    
    echo "2 дабла - невероятная удача.";
} elseif ($anonSum > $compSum); {
    echo "Анон победил !";
} elseif ($anonSum < $compSum); {
    echo "Компьютер Победил!";
} else ($anonSum == $compSum); {
    echo "Ничья :(";
}

exit();
```

Comment: удобнее будет смотреть здесь http://ideone.com/Wl3Y9D

Comment: Неужели так сложно отформатировать код самому?

Answer (score 2):

У вас лишние символы `;` в блоках условий. Кроме того, блок `else` не должен содержать условий. Рабочий код может выглядеть как-то так:

```
error_reporting (-1);

$anonDice1 = mt_rand(1,6);
$compDice1 = mt_rand(1,6);
$anonDice2 = mt_rand(1,6);
$compDice2 = mt_rand(1,6);

echo "У анона выпало {$anonDice1} и {$anonDice2}\nУ компьютера выпало {$compDice1} и {$compDice2}\n";

// Эти строки скорее всего делают не то, что вам кажется...
$anonSum - ($anonDice1 + $anonDice2);
$compSum - ($compDice1 + $compDice2);

if (($anonDice1 == $anonDice2) && ($compDice1 == $compDice2)) {    
    echo "2 дабла - невероятная удача.";
} elseif ($anonSum > $compSum) {
    echo "Анон победил !";
} elseif ($anonSum < $compSum) {
    echo "Компьютер Победил!";
} else {
    echo "Ничья :(";
}

exit();
```

От том, как должны выглядеть структуры `if/elseif/else` см.: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: А именно http://take.ms/Sh7Qs